# How to run a shell script on 10 hosts simultaneously?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ssh

Currently I am monitoring 10 hosts. I want to write a script which will calculate the disk space in every 24 hours and then if the file system of a host is critical for any host then it will move the old files from that host to the host which has the largest disk space?

Answer (score 1):

There exist parallel ssh wrappers -- here are a few I found on CentOS7/EPEL:

```
    Name        : pssh
    Repo        : epel/x86_64
    Summary     : Parallel SSH tools
    URL         : http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/
    License     : BSD
    Description : This package provides various parallel tools based on ssh and scp.
                : Parallell version includes:
                :  o ssh : pssh
                :  o scp : pscp
                :  o nuke : pnuke
                :  o rsync : prsync
                :  o slurp : pslurp

    Name        : pdsh
    Repo        : epel/x86_64
    Summary     : Parallel remote shell program
    URL         : https://pdsh.googlecode.com/
    License     : GPLv2+
    Description : Pdsh is a multithreaded remote shell client which executes commands
                : on multiple remote hosts in parallel.  Pdsh can use several different
                : remote shell services, including standard "rsh", Kerberos IV, and ssh.

    Name        : mpssh
    Repo        : epel/x86_64
    Summary     : Parallel ssh tool
    URL         : https://github.com/ndenev/mpssh
    License     : BSD
    Description : mpssh is a parallel ssh tool. What it does is connecting to a number of hosts
                : specified in the hosts file and execute the same command on all of them
```

So you could use that script to query the remote systems over ssh to get their disk space, and then evaluate which to clean up, and which to use as a destination.

Answer (score 0):

This will run a script on the specified list of hosts in parallel:

```
declare -a CLEANUP
for host in host1.example.com host2.example.com; do # the list can be as long as you need
   OUTPUT="/tmp/${host}.out"
   ssh "$host" '/path/to/script' > "$OUTPUT" &
   CLEANUP+=("$OUTPUT")
done
trap 'rm -fr "${OUTPUT[@]}"' EXIT
# How to parse the output files is an exercise I leave to you
```